# Behave Django Testing - Behave testing only uses dev database instead of test database

Tags: python, django, cucumber, python-behave

How to properly set up behave-django so that it can use a test database loaded with data using factories?

Please have a look to the code I have written.

**environment.py**

```
environment.py

import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'SampleDemo.settings')
django.setup()

from behave import fixture, use_fixture
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
from django.test.testcases import TransactionTestCase, TestCase


from src.core.models import User


class BaseTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        User.objects.create_superuser(username='setuadmin', password='admin', email='setuadmin@admin.com')
        super(BaseTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        User.objects.filter().delete()
        super(BaseTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()


@fixture
def django_test_case(context):
    context.test_case = BaseTestCase
    context.test_case.setUpClass()
    yield
    context.test_case.tearDownClass()
    del context.test_case


def before_all(context):
    django.setup()
    context.test_runner = DiscoverRunner()
    context.test_runner.setup_test_environment()
    context.old_db_config = context.test_runner.setup_databases()
    yield
    context.test_runner.teardown_databases(context.old_db_config)
    context.test_runner.teardown_test_environment()


def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    use_fixture(django_test_case, context)
```

**feature file**

```
Feature: Polish Grading CRUD
  Test CRUD methods of Polish-Grading Module REST API testing framework
  Background:
    Given I set REST API server url


  Scenario: User login with valid credentials
    Given I provide user authentication credentials
    And I make an http post call to "/user/login/" api
    Then I must get a response with status code 200 and a jSon object with token

  Scenario: fetch grading details
    Given I provide the params to fetch polish-grading details
    When I set the HEADER param request content type as "application/json".
    And I send HTTP GET request as "/polish/fetch-grading/"
    Then I receive the Valid HTTP Response code 200 for "GET".
```

**steps.py**

```
import json
import requests
from behave import *

from configs.acceptance_test_config import AcceptanceTestConfigs

request_headers = {}



@given("I set REST API server url")
def step_impl(context):
    context.server_url = AcceptanceTestConfigs.SERVER_URL.value


@given("I provide user authentication credentials")
def step_impl(context):
    context.headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
    context.body = {
          "username": "setuadmin",
          "password": "admin"
    }


@given('I make an http post call to "{login_endpoint}" api')
def step_impl(context, login_endpoint):
    context.res = requests.post(
        context.server_url + login_endpoint,
        data=json.dumps(context.body),
        headers=context.headers,
    )
    assert context.res.status_code == 200


@then("I must get a response with status code 200 and a jSon object with token")
def step_impl(context):
    if context.res.status_code == 200:
        global access_token
        access_token = json.loads(context.res.text)["access"]



@given(u'I provide the params to fetch polish-grading details')
def step_impl(context):
    context.params = {"kapan_no":2210, "packet_no":16.000}


@when(u'I set the HEADER param request content type as "{header_content_type}".')
def step_impl(context, header_content_type):
    request_headers['Content-Type'] = header_content_type
    request_headers['Authorization'] = f"Bearer {access_token}"


@when(u'I send HTTP GET request as "{polish_grading_endpoint}"')
def step_impl(context, polish_grading_endpoint):
    polish_grading_api_url = context.server_url + polish_grading_endpoint
    context.response = requests.get(url=polish_grading_api_url, headers=request_headers, params=context.params)


@then(u'I receive the Valid HTTP Response code 200 for "GET".')
def step_impl(context):
        if context.response is not None:
            assert context.response.status_code == 200
```

Above code creates a test database, loads data using UserFactory and Also destroys the Test Database, But when I run BDD test via `python manage.py behave` it pointing **dev database** instead of Test Database.

When I try to loging using a user registered in DEV database, Tests passes successfully. When I try to login with the user created in Test Database, tests are getting failed.

**OUTPUT**

**while running with Dev DB user credentials**

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Feature: Polish Grading CRUD # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/features/fetch_polish_grading.feature:1
  Test CRUD methods of Polish-Grading Module REST API testing 
  Background:   # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/features/fetch_polish_grading.feature:3

  Scenario: User login with valid credentials                                    # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/features/fetch_polish_grading.feature:7
    Given I set REST API server url                                              # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:14 0.000s
    Given I provide user authentication credentials                              # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py    Given I provide user authentication credentials                              # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:19 0.000ssername': 'kruti123', 'password': 'Shairu@1234'}
    And I make an http post call to "/user/login/" api                           # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:33
    And I make an http post call to "/user/login/" api                           # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:33 0.283spoint.
    Then I must get a response with status code 200 and a jSon object with token # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:47 0.000s


  Scenario: fetch grading details                                           # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/features/fetch_polish_grading.feature:12
    Given I set REST API server url                                         # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:14 0.000s
    Given I provide the params to fetch polish-grading details              # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:54 0.000s
    When I set the HEADER param request content type as "application/json". # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:59
   When I set the HEADER param request content type as "application/json". # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:59 0.000s
    And I send HTTP GET request as "/polish/fetch-grading/"                 # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:66 0.062s
    Then I receive the Valid HTTP Response code 200 for "GET".              # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:72 0.000s

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
2 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
9 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.347s
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

**while running with Test DB user Credentials**

```
Background:   # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/features/fetch_polish_grading.feature:3

  Scenario: User login with valid credentials                                    # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/features/fetch_polish_grading.feature:7
    Given I set REST API server url                                              # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:14 0.000s
    Given I provide user authentication credentials                              # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py    Given I provide user authentication credentials                              # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:19 0.002ssername': 'setuadmin', 'password': 'admin'}
    And I make an http post call to "/user/login/" api                           # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:33
    And I make an http post call to "/user/login/" api                           # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:33 0.354spoint.
    Then I must get a response with status code 200 and a jSon object with token # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:47 0.000s

  Scenario: fetch grading details                                           # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/features/fetch_polish_grading.feature:12
    Given I set REST API server url                                         # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:14 0.000s
    Given I provide the params to fetch polish-grading details              # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:54 0.000s
    When I set the HEADER param request content type as "application/json". # src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py:59 0.001s
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/tntra-kanan/tntra-projects/setu/setu_backend_app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1329, in run
          match.run(runner.context)
        File "/home/tntra-kanan/tntra-projects/setu/setu_backend_app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/behave/matchers.py", line 98, in run
          self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
        File "src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/steps/fetch_grading_details.py", line 62, in step_impl
      NameError: name 'access_token' is not defined

    And I send HTTP GET request as "/polish/fetch-grading/"                 # None
    Then I receive the Valid HTTP Response code 200 for "GET".              # None


Failing scenarios:
  src/polish_grading_management/tests/acceptance/features/fetch_polish_grading.feature:12  fetch grading details

0 features passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
6 steps passed, 1 failed, 2 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.358s
```